# Unable to load package for //:abc/requirements.txt while generating par files using bazel

Tags: bazel

I am trying to generate par files for my target. But it is unable to load the package present in one of the requirements.txt file mentioned in WORKSPACE. I m unable to figure what is actually expecting.

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'requirements.bzl': no such package '@abc_deps//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pog/4dbff95ef3b73130029b349a5743e7e7/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 26
            repository_ctx.execute(["python", repository_ctx.path(r...("")])
    File "/tmp/.cache/bazel/_bazel_pog/4dbff95ef3b73130029b349a5743e7e7/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 32, in repository_ctx.execute
            repository_ctx.path(repository_ctx.attr.requirements)
```

Unable to load package for //:abc/requirements.txt: not found.

Steps followed to install bazel in centos 7:

```
    wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.17.2/bazel-0.17.2-linux-x86_64 -O ./bazel
    chmod +x ./bazel
    yum -y install gcc
    sudo yum install gcc-c++
    sudo yum install python-devel
    sudo yum install openldap-devel
```

Comment: How did you install bazel? Which tutorial did u follow?

Comment: I have updated the steps followed in the question